# Linq in wcf service

Tags: c#, linq

So Im returning a collection from my GET request and I noticed I want to return a group based on `anyofthebelow` rather than individually:

> StudentID
>
> FirstName
>
> LastName

I only know how to do it in the code below while then having to create different GET methods for each, is there a way I could call the `GetStudentCollectionByGroup(string anything)` and return the above list of specifics from my client without having to do the below method for each `StudentID, FirstName, LastName`?

```
   public List<Group> GetStudentCollectionByGroup(string studentID)
    {
        List<Group> groups = (from g in Groups
                              where
                                  (from t in g.Groupsz where t.StudentID == studentID select t).Count() > 0
                              select g).ToList();
        return groups;
    }

    public List<Group> GetStudentCollectionByGroup(string firstName)
    {
        List<Group> groups = (from g in Groups
                              where
                                  (from t in g.Groupsz where t.FirstName == firstName select t).Count() > 0
                              select g).ToList();
        return groups;
    }
```

For instance:

```
from t in g.Groupsz where t.StudentID == studentID select t
```

Is there an OR method? Something like:

```
where t.StudentID == anything OR t.FirstName == anything etc
```

**p.s not very sure on how to word the title for this (edits welcome)**

Comment: Watch the case sensativity in you name comparision. BOB != Bob != bob. You probably should use a comparison method that allows you to control the case like String.Compare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course; you can use the `||` operator:

```
where t.StudentID == studentID || t.FirstName == firstName
```